# Iterated Expectation when Prior is a Function -- what are the constraints?

Tags: probability-theory

I have the expression

$$E[E[Y|g(X)]] = E[Y]$$

and am trying to determine for what functions $g$ this holds true.

The expression is similar to iterated expectation.  I believe the only valid answer is $g(X)=f(X|Y)$ because anything else will prevent the term $f(Y|X)f(X)=f(Y)$ from forming during the development of the iterate expectation theorem.  Is this correct?

Comment: If $E|Y|<\infty$, then $E[E[Y|g(X)]] = E[Y]$ holds for any (Borel measurable) $g$ and $X$. So we don't need any additional conditions.

Comment: The point is that $E[E[Y|Z]] = E[Y]$ for **any** random variable $Z$, as long as $E[Y]$ is defined.  So in particular this works for $Z = g(X)$ as long as that is a random variable.